# Is VisualStudio 2015 android emulator is able to emulate the TrustZone?

Tags: emulation, trustzone

I am doing a research about apps using Trustzone in Android. Just wondering that is VisualStudio 2015 Emulator is able the emulate the environment?

Thanks in Advance

Rong